# What is the e specifier for LaTeX3 and where is it documented?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Pages 1-2 of interface3.pdf, "The LaTeX3 Interfaces" released 2018-10-31, only lists specifiers of `c`,`D`, `F`, `f`, `N`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `T`, `V`, `v`, `w` and `x`. The `e` specifier of `\str_if_eq:eeTF` is not in that list. What does it mean and where is it documented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a wrapper for the `\expanded` primitive that is in luatex and in xetex/ptex/pdftex in texlive 2019, see interface3 on page 27 which says

> \exp_args:Ne function { tokens }
>
> This function absorbs two arguments (the function name and the tokens)
>   and exhaustively expands the tokens. The result is inserted in
>   braces into the input stream after reinsertion of the function. Thus
>   the function may take more than one argument: all others are left
>   unchanged.
>
> TeXhackers note: This relies on the \expanded primitive when available
>   (in LuaTeX and starting around 2019 in other engines). Otherwise it
>   uses some fall-back code that is very much slower. As a result it
>   should only be used in performance-critical code if typical users have
>   a recent installation of the TeX ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks; I dropped them a note asking to include the relevant material from Section V on pp. 1-2.

Comment: @shmuel yes I got the email:-)